# D3 Tooltip for updated pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

So I've created a pie chart that takes in some JSON data. Upon clicking a radio button, the pie chart's data will update depending on what option is chosen. However, I'm running into an issue because I'd like to put a D3 tooltip on the pie chart and have its values update whenever the pie chart updates... anyone know the best way to do that?

Here's what my pie chart looks like so far:

```
<form>
    <label><input type="radio" name="dataset" value="females" checked> Females </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="dataset" value="males"> Males </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="dataset" value="totalNumber"> Both </label>
  </form>

  <script>
  var width = 760, height = 300, radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  var legendRectSize = 18;
  var legendSpacing = 4;

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(["7-15", "16-24", "25-33", "34-42", "43-51", "52-60", "61-70"])
      .range(["#ff8b3d", "#d65050", "#ab0e4d", "#6f0049", "#4a004b", "#d0743c", "#BE2625"]);

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius * 0.9)
      .innerRadius(radius * 0.3);

  var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
      .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(d) { return d.females; });

  var svg = d3.select("#donut1").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 4 + "," + height / 2 + ")")

  d3.json("graphdata.php", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      var path = svg.datum(data).selectAll("path")
      .data(pie)
      d.females = +d.females;
      d.males = +d.males;
      d.totalNumber = +d.totalNumber;
    });

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([55, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return ("Victims:") + " " + d[value] + "<br>";
      })

    svg.call(tip);

    var donut1 = svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(data))
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .on("mouseover", tip.show)
        .on("mouseout", tip.hide);

    donut1.append("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .each(function(d) {this._current = d; }); //stores the initial angles


  /*Control for changing the radio buttons & filtering the data*/
  d3.selectAll("input")
    .on("change", change);

    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      d3.select("input[value=\"females\"]").property("checked", true).each(change);}, 2000);

    function change() {
      var path = svg.datum(data).selectAll("path")
      var value = this.value;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      pie.value(function(d) { return d[value]; }); //change value function
      tip.html(function(d) { return "Victims:" + " " + d[value]; }); //change the tooltip
      path = path.data(pie); //compute new angles
      path.transition().duration(1800).attrTween("d", arcTween); //redraw the arcs, please!
    }

    function type(d) {
      d.females = +d.females;
      d.males = +d.males;
      d.totalNumber = +d.totalNumber;
      return d;
    }

    //Store displayed angles in _current
    //Interpolate them from _current to new angles
    //_current is updated in-place by d3.interpolate during transition
    function arcTween(a) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
      this._current = i(0);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(i(t));
      };
    }
```

I know that the key lies in the change() function and within this line:

```
tip.html(function(d) { return "Victims:" + " " + d[value]; }); //change the tooltip
```

But d[value] is undefined when I try to use it on that line. I'm just not sure what else it could be..

*edit:*
Here's the graphdata.php file contents:

```
<?php include("connectDB.php");

$query = "SELECT sum(sex ='M') males, sum(sex ='F') females, CASE
WHEN age BETWEEN 7 AND 15 THEN '7-15'
WHEN age <= 24 THEN '16-24'
WHEN age <= 33 THEN '25-33'
WHEN age <= 42 THEN '34-42'
WHEN age <= 51 THEN '43-51'
WHEN age <= 52 THEN '52-60'
WHEN age <= 70 THEN '61-70'
END AS age,
COUNT(*) AS totalNumber

FROM people

GROUP BY CASE
WHEN age <= 15 THEN '7-15'
WHEN age <= 24 THEN '16-24'
WHEN age <= 33 THEN '25-33'
WHEN age <= 42 THEN '34-42'
WHEN age <= 51 THEN '43-51'
WHEN age <= 52 THEN '52-60'
WHEN age <= 70 THEN '61-70'
END";

$data = array(); 

if($result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
}

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Comment: post what is graphdata.php? - a working demo will be helpful.

Comment: After the data has been "pie-ed", `d.value` will contain the point, just use `tip.html(function(d) { return "Victims:" + " " + d["value"]; });` or `tip.html(function(d) { return "Victims:" + " " + d.value; });`

Comment: @Mark that's what I thought would be the case. However, when I try `tip.html(function(d) { return "Victims:" + " " + d["value"]; });` or  `tip.html(function(d) { return "Victims:" + " " + d.value; });`, I only get the d.females values, regardless if I update the graph.

Comment: So it seems as though it has something to do with this line: `var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) { return d.females; });` ... It's automatically pulling the female values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a friend to help me out. What he ended up doing was this:

```
function change() {
      var path = svg.datum(data).selectAll("path")
      var value = this.value;
      clearTimeout(timeout);

      pie.value(function(d) { return d[value]; }); //change value function

      tip.html(function(d) {
            console.log($( "input:checked" ).val() );
        if($( "input:checked" ).val() == "males") {
            hoverValue = d.data.males;
        }
        if($( "input:checked" ).val() == "females") {
            hoverValue = d.data.females;
        }
        if($( "input:checked" ).val() == "totalNumber") {
            hoverValue = d.data.totalNumber;
        }
        return "Victims:" + " " +hoverValue;
      }); //change the tooltip
      path = path.data(pie); //compute new angles
      path.transition().duration(1800).attrTween("d", arcTween); //redraw the arcs, please!
    }
```

In particular, what has changed is the tip.html function. We take the value of whatever radio value input is checked and use it to determine what data to display. However, my data was located further down into the object, so we had to navigate like so: `d.data.males`, for example. We set that value to a variable and call it in the return so that it displays in the tooltip.